# Modifying view from Action Helper in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to modify a view from Action Helper in Zend Framework in preDispatch() method.
So I do something like:

```
class MyHelper extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract {
    public function preDispatch() {
        $view = $this->getActionController()->view;
        $view->doSomething();
    }
}
```

Is it OK to do so? What I want to do is - MyHelper needs to adjust some paths to templates (in this case view is a SmartyView) according to users locale, so I would like to read out users locale in my action helper and then adjust view accordingly.

I am doing right here or should I go some different way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do it with an ActionHelper. But you would have to call it explicitly then. The `preDispatch` callback method does not exist in an [Action Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html). If you want to use the dispatch callbacks, you are looking for a [Zend Controller Plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html).

An alternative to your approach would be to init [`Zend_Locale`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.html) in your bootstrap, before initializing `Zend_View`. You could then fetch the locale when initializing `Zend_View` and adjust paths directly during bootstrap, instead of during the dispatch cycle. See the examples on [`Zend_Application`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.examples.html) for an idea.

Comment: I did use Zend_Locale in bootstrap before, but the path adjustments depends not only on locale, but could also depend let's say on request parameters, so doing this in bootstrap is probably not the best way to do it... I'll try going with controller plugins, thanks!

Comment: How do I access view object from Zend Controller Plugin? Somehow I cannot see it anywhere on plugin object...

Comment: @Laimoncijus You could do `Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()`